# Default function Variables in PHP versus Python

Tags: php, python, function, default-value

In Python it is possible to have a function with several variables all having a default value. And then just passing the value of one of the values. So if I have

```
function foo(a=10,b=50, c=70)
    pass
    pass
    return
```

Then I can call

```
foo(b=29)
```

and it would call

```
foo(10,29,70)
```

*(using the default for all the values, and the exact value for that one variable).*

**Is something similar possible in PHP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no equivalent to that in PHP. You can have default values for function arguments, but they are evaluated from left to right and are not named:

```
function test($var1 = 'default1', $var2 = 'default2')
{

}
```

In that example the two variables are optional, but you must specify the first argument if you want to specify the second.

```
test(); // works
test('arg1'); // works
test('arg1', 'arg2'); // works
test('arg2'); // this will set the first argument, not the second.
```

A common workaround if you need flexibility on your optional arguments is to pass an array as the argument:

```
function test($options)
{

}
```

This can have a variable number of arguments in the form of a single associative array:

```
$options = array('var1' => 'arg1', 'var2' => 'arg2');
test($options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array as an argument. For example:

```
function a(array $params) {
    $defaults = array(
        'a' => 10,
        'b' => 50,
        'c' => 70,
    );
    $params += $defaults;
    // use $params
}

a(array('b' => 29));
```

Comment: WOW! In the code I am writing right now it would be an overkill. But it's a really interesting solution.

Comment: If you have lots of arguments (and many of them are not required), usually I would recommend to pass only one argument of some structure. As arrays are simple solution (as in the example), I would suggest to make class which would represent the arguments. For example, `function search(Filter $filter)` and `Filter` class would hold the parameters themselves. This provides greater readability (as you don't have to count 8th argument etc) but sometimes can be overengeneering.